# jQuery fire an event n times using a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I'm trying to fire click event multiple times using a for loop but it only triggers 3 times.

```
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        $('.slideview-next').click();

      }
```

I actually tried pasting `$('.slideview-next').click();` to the chrome dev tools five times on a single line but still it only fire 3 times

Comment: What happens on `click()`?

Comment: Your `edit` does — not — work. That only binds a `click event handler`. Where is the one with the `trigger()`?

Comment: try $('.slideview-next').trigger("click"); instead

Comment: Hi, I already tested $('.slideview-next').trigger("click"); same thing happens, the event fires only 3 times

Comment: @user3344741 can you add more details code ? Its hard to identify whats going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As I read it, what you're trying to achieve is to fire off multiple 'actions/outcomes' from 1 click? What's happening in the above code is that you are binding the `click event` to the `slide-view-next` element(s) 10 times.  The `click` event handler takes a callback that it will execute when the element has been clicked.  It's within this callback function that you can place your for loop. Something like this:

```
$('.slideview-next').click(function() {
  for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   console.log(i); // place anything you want done 10 times from 1 click
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sagokharche/a4zszgL4/)

```
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button class="slideview-next">Change color</button>
</div>

JS Code

// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  console.log(1);
})

for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  $('.slideview-next').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        $('.slideview-next').click(
        function(){
        alert("clicked");
         });
}
```

```css
.slideview-next{
background-color : red;
height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideview-next"></div>
```

It works for entire for loop. can you post your code what are you trying to achieve on click function? it will give more insight of problem.

Comment: Sorry but, binding 10 times the same event doen't seem a good answer

Comment: Ya definitely it isn't a good approach were just trying to replicate the issue.